# How to convert two array into an object in mongoDB where the first array has multiple same values

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-compass

After some processing with a mongo aggregation, I have a collection like :

```
[{
 field1: 10,
 field2: 50,
 field3: { 
           name: ["a","b","a","a"], 
           value: [1,2,3,4]
         }
},...]
```

I am struggling finding a way to convert it into :

```
[{
 field1: 10,
 field2: 50,
 a:[1,3,4],
 b:[2]
},...]
```

Using mongo aggregation in mongoshell or compass

Comment: will the length of `name` and `value` arrays will always be equal? Also what is your MongoDB version?

Comment: Yes it is always equal, and it is MongoDB 4.2.6 !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the idea is to:

1. Pick one of the array from `field3` say `name` to generate array range `[0, 1, 2, 3]`.
2. Loop through `name` and `value` array simultaneously to get an array of `{ k: "", v: "" }`.
3. `$unwind` the array from previous stage for grouping.
4. Group by key `field3.k` to accumulate all values `field3.v`.
5. Again group by `null` to generate an array of pattern `{ k: "", v: "" }`.
6. Concatenate `field1` and `field2` into the array from previous stage.
7. Finally convert the array to object using `$arrayToObject`.

Try this:

```js
db.testCollection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            field3: {
                $map: {
                    input: { $range: [0, { $size: "$field3.name" }] },
                    as: "index",
                    in: {
                        k: { $arrayElemAt: ["$field3.name", "$$index"] },
                        v: { $arrayElemAt: ["$field3.value", "$$index"] }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$field3" },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$field3.k",
            field1: { $first: "$field1" },
            field2: { $first: "$field2" },
            k: { $first: "$field3.k" },
            v: { $push: "$field3.v" }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            field1: { $first: "$field1" },
            field2: { $first: "$field2" },
            array: {
                $push: { k: "$k", v: "$v" }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            array: {
                $concatArrays: [
                    [{ k: "field1", v: "$field1" }, { k: "field2", v: "$field2" }],
                    "$array"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: { $arrayToObject: "$array" }
        }
    }
]);
```

Output

```js
{
    "field1" : 10,
    "field2" : 50,
    "a" : [
        1,
        3,
        4
    ],
    "b" : [
        2
    ]
}
```

Comment: You can also `$zip` operator: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/zip/

Comment: Thank you, it worked like a charm and now I understand better how to handle similar situation I might encounter !